# How to add a new line to a file from Makefile with non-GNU sed

Tags: unix, sed

I'm trying to write a make target that will add a new line to an existing file. This is what I wrote:

```
target:
    sed -i '' '1 i\ \
    <line to be added> \
    ' <filename>
```

This raised an error `extra characters after \ at the end of i command` because of the space between the two backslashes on the first line. I can't put them all in one line either because I'm using a non-GNU sed, or more specifically the one on macOS.

What is the proper way to do it?

Comment: You can maybe work around with `echo "new line" > tempfile; cat existing >> tempfile; mv tempfile existing`

Comment: That was what I ended up doing... I was wondering if anyone run into the same problem and found a proper way of solving it

Answer (score 1):

I have a really, excessively ugly answer for you! :-)

If you make `bash` your shell in your Makefile, you can use a `bash-ism` to generate a newline for `sed` with `$'\n'` as follows:

```
sed -e '1i\'$'\n''line to be added' file
```

Then, if you want to put that into a Makefile, you need to double up the dollar sign, so you get this ugly monstrosity!

```
SHELL := /bin/bash

target: 
    sed -e '1i\'$$'\n''line to be added' file
```